# Receive an array via $resource get method

Tags: angularjs

```
Edited: Now this example fully works with external json service to see it in live
```

I can see the received array and params in the console.log, but I can't echo that array to the view...

That online JSON service returns `{"key": "value"}`

How to make this `{{some_item.key}}` to work? Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Simple">
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">    
    {{some_item.key}}
</div>
<script>
angular.module('Simple', ['ngResource']);
function SimpleController($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.simple = $resource('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value',
        {callback:'JSON_CALLBACK'},
        {get:{method:'JSONP'}}
    );
    $scope.some_item = $scope.simple.get();
    console.log($scope.some_item.key);
}   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `$scope.some_item[0]`. Arrays values are accessed via an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the interpolation inside the controller's scope like this

```
<div ng-controller="SimpleController">    
    {{some_item.key}}
</div>
```